# Получение данных из базы до отправки формы

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

У меня бд с пользователями. С помощью `ajax` я получаю `email` пользователя из выпадающего списка в модальное окно. **Вопрос в том чтобы в это же модальное окно получать `born_date` и `phone_number` этого пользователя по его `email`**, и после уже отправлять форму на обработку. У меня не работает что-то. В чем ошибка может быть?

Вот структура бд:
[image]

`python:`

```
description = ['mymail@gmail','mymail@gmail','uuser@mail.ru','mymail2222@gmail','my1212mail@gmail','11mymail@gmail']


@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'loggedin' in session:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users.data WHERE description = 'description'")
        account = cur.fetchall()
        description = account
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'],
                                                firstname=session['firstname'], description=description)


@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
def profile_post():
    data = request.json
    data_list = list(data.values())

    data_list = str(data_list)
    doc_data = data_list.split()[2][:-4]

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % doc_data.replace("'", ""))
    account = cur.fetchone()

born = account[0]
num = account[1]


    print('Got data:', data)
    return jsonify({
        'status': 'SUCCESS',
        'data': data,
    })


return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], born=born, num=num)
```

`html`

```
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="optionClick(this)">
    {% for descr in description%}
        <option id="val" value="{{descr}}">{{ descr }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="process();">
    Process
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style='font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 18px;'>Information about user</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="form-control" id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>


        <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">Born date is: {{ born }}</h2>
        <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">Phone number is: {{ num }}</h2>


        <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Send Data
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
    


<script type="text/javascript">
function printValue(selectedItem) {
    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value.replace(/[{()}]/g, '').replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[{,}]/g, ''));
    console.log(typeof(selectedItem.value));
}
function process(selectedItem) {
    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
    document.getElementById('#exampleModalCenter')
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "selectedItems": $('#sel').val()
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/profile",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
function optionClick(selectedItem) {
    printValue(selectedItem);
}
</script>
```

Comment: *Вопрос в том чтобы в это же модальное окно получать born_date и phone_number этого пользователя по его email, и после уже отправлять форму на обработку.* Гм... зачем? Вы хотите их отобразить на форме между моментами выбора даты и отправки запроса на обработку? а если нет - то более чем достаточно получить эти данные в запросе на сервере и не гонять их бесцельно туда-сюда.

Comment: До записи данных в БД или после?

Comment: "У меня не работает что-то". Сложно отвечать на такие вопросы, не находите ? Не выполняется запрос ? Не передаёт на рендер результаты запроса ? AJAX запрос не получает ответа от сервера ? Что Вы делали что бы разобраться в проблеме и где застряли ?