# получение ключа из json объекта

Tags: python, json, flask

У меня есть форма из которой я с помощью `ajax` получаю `json` объект вида:

```
{'selectedItems': ["('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'mymail@gmail.com')"]}
```

Такой вопрос: **Как отсюда получать только `email` как строку?** Я пытался ковертировать в список потом в строку, но ошибку дает при отправлении `None type object`. Помогите решить.

```
data = request.json
data_list = list(data.values())

data_list = str(data_list)
doc_data = data_list.split()
```

`html:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function process(selectedItem) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/profile",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
<script>
```

Comment: Как я понимаю вот это `"('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'mymail@gmail.com')"` строка. элемент списка значений `selectedItems`. Так?

Comment: @Namerek, да, правильно поняли. То есть я сразу получаю имя, фамилию и мейл пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о реализации на Python, то как-то вот так

```py
import re


def str_value_to_list(text: str):
    *_, email = re.findall(r'[^ \',()]+', text)
    return email


item = {'selectedItems': ["('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'mymail@gmail.com')"]}
print(str_value_to_list(item['selectedItems'][0]))
# mymail@gmail.com
```

К примеру для вывода всех email в одном `selectedItems` в виде списка можно использовать такой код:

```py
import re


def str_value_to_list(items: list):
    result = [email for *_, email in [re.findall(r'[^ \',()]+', text) for text in items]]

    return result


item = {'selectedItems': ["('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'mymail@gmail.com')"]}
print(str_value_to_list(item['selectedItems']))

# ['mymail@gmail.com']
```

Comment: я когда отправляю форму после получение мейла из json получаю такую ошибку: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @abby, А можно больше вариантов вывода, в том числе включающие пустые выдачи. Как я понимаю некоторые из результатов запроса выглядят так `{'selectedItems': []}` Ну или очень похоже, и желательно опишите что вы потом с этими емейлами делаете (ну всмысле список из них составляете или еще какие операции, тоесть как вы их потом используете в коде

Comment: ну пустых там нет. только  это, просто каждый раз туда попадает разный мейл который выбирает сам юзер. Этот мейл появляется в модальном окне и с этого модального окна отправляется форма. Но тут происходит выше написанная ошибка. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150706/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B) вся информация

Comment: А Вы можете по шагам объяснить, что Вы делаете в этой `def profile_post())` функции?

Comment: смотрите. как только страница открылась из списка выбираете юзера и жмете get info, открывается модальное окно и в нем в первой строке email того юзера которого выбрали из списка. И вот на этот email я отправляю сообщение, а когда жму `send` выходит та ошибка

Comment: Я немного не это имел ввиду, на сколько я понимаю, по вашему замыслу в переменной `doc_data` должна содержаться строка, но поскольку `data_list.split()[2][:-4]` дает список (даже пусть из одного элемента), то `doc_data.replace("'", "")` Просто должно выдать исключение поскольку `list` не имеет функции `replace()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110528/discussion-between-namerek-and-abby).

Comment: ответил в чате вам